# Android 5.0 Notification

Tags: android, notifications

Every time I run my application, the notification symbol in the notification bar is just a white square. My notification worked fine on all other android versions except for lollipop. I have looked at other threads and they don't seem to work. Anyone have any suggestions?

I have attached a picture of the notification icon I want to use:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhJcA.gif

It is a 48x48 gif. file with a transparent background. I have also tried a 16x16 gif file and I still had no luck.

Comment: The linked image renders in Chrome as a white square.

Comment: Save it to your computer. It should be an exclamation mark in a transparent background.

Comment: Android doesn't do a lot with GIFs. Try converting it to a PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

Lollipop changes the notification styling according to this [Behavior Changes](http://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fabout%2Fversions%2Fandroid-5.0-changes.html&ei=uJEIVd3WLZL1aPn2gPgJ&usg=AFQjCNGjvjghMXrA4DVn7ouLr_WiXpP5GA&sig2=FbFCR8gy3CWCAJuLLidQkg&bvm=bv.88198703,d.d2s&cad=rja). It changes the background of the notification circle to be white so white on white will not work, but you can change that to any color you want by

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.my_notif_color);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setColor(color);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

As [hegazy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790464/hegazy) has explained the new notification styling causes that.

Notice that if you are not using any new functionality, as a workaround you can stay with previous styling by setting the target SDK to 20 max: `android:targetSdkVersion="20"`